# How to get user email by display name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Get email id by display name - How to get user email by display name in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use these lines of code, you will find the result :

```
<?php  
    global $wpdb;
    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users WHERE display_name = 'your_user_display_name'");
    $required_user_email = $users[0]->user_email;
    echo $required_user_email;
?>
```

Just replace 'your_user_display_name' with display name of the user for which you want to get the email

Comment: Although WordPress database structure is stable, issuing "direct" queries can lead to future problems. User manipulation has a specific API. I strongly recommend using the [`WP_User_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: Somewhat simpler:
`$required_user_email = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users WHERE display_name = 'your_user_display_name'");`

Answer (score -2):

<s>Try [get_user_by($field,$value) function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)</s>

```
 <?php $user = get_user_by( 'display_name', 'John Doe' ); ?>
```

This could be dangerous because display name is not unique!

**Edit**

You can also use the [class `WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
$query = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'search' => 'John Doe',
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_nicename' ),
));

// User Loop
if ( empty( $query->results ) )
    throw new Exception('no user found');

foreach ( $query->results as $user )
    echo $user->email,PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: But i want to get all user's email by display name.

Comment: @RahulVaghela Ok, you'll be fine with `get_user_by` function.
Of course you'll have to iterate the result set and grab email addresses (a `while` loop, easy)

Comment: There is no such thing as `get_user_by( 'display_name', ... )`

Comment: `get_user_by` is actually using `WP_User::get_data_by` were the only possible fields are `'id', 'ID', 'slug', 'email' or 'login'`. More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/get_data_by/). Your edit seems to be a good solution.